# Instant messaging app (Whatsapp, Viber, Wechat, etc.) keeps showing deleted image

Tags: whatsapp, viber, lumia-950

few days ago I moved some photo albums from my computer to my phone and then I deleted them using my pc. Now the photos are no longer present in file explorer , but when I want to attach a photo or a video from an app like WhatsApp or Viber it keeps on showing previews of deleted albums. I can see those photos but when I try to select tem a message pops up "Impossible to open photo. It could be lost or damaged".

Is it possible to remove the preview of deleted photos?

I've a Lumia 950 with windows phone 10.

Comment: Try doing a soft reset, maybe this will clear the cache.

Answer (score 4):

Even if u delete the file from the storage(phone/sd card) the application will have the record of the file stored (as Cache memory), it'll be in blurred state. Best option delete the media through the application.

1. From the app select the messages - Images, music, videos, and delete them.
2. Or you an clear the chat history - which will delete all chat messages inside chat including texts.
3. Or Reset your app (do this only if other option doesn't work).